# Strange text spacing within an accordion button

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling with some weird spacing within an accordion button. Is there a way I can make it more uniform?

I have tried removing all `&nbsp` tags and tried adding margins.

```html
<button class="accordion">What can I expect at my hotel?</button>

<div class="panel">
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">All rooms will have a hairdryer, an iron, a small safe and tea and coffee making facilities. Basic Wi-Fi is included.</span></span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Check-in is from 4pm and check-out by 12pm.</span></span></p>
</div>
```

The result should be two paragraphs of text with uniform margins on the top and bottom but what i actually get is a large space at the top and a small one at the bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<style>
  p {
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 30px 0px;
  }
</style>

<button class="accordion">What can I expect at my hotel?</button>

<div class="panel">

<p><span><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">All rooms will have a hairdryer, an iron, a small safe and tea and coffee making facilities. Basic Wi-Fi is included.</span></span></p>

<p><span><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Check-in is from 4pm and check-out by 12pm.</span></span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this just results in a very tiny gap at the top and a line sized gap at the bottom.

Comment: That seems to add a margin below the unopened button rather than the text itself.

Comment: @CameronGrigsby OK, that should do it now.

Comment: All fixed. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

By default, CSS adds some default margin and paddings to your elements and you should always start with a universal reset as I've done in the CSS code to remove this unwanted behavior. And then you can define your own margins and padding as you intend.

```css
*,*:before,*:after {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">What can I expect at my hotel?</button>

<div class="panel">
<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">All rooms will have a hairdryer, an iron, a small safe and tea and coffee making facilities. Basic Wi-Fi is included.</span></span></p>

<p><span style="font-size:16px"><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif">Check-in is from 4pm and check-out by 12pm.</span></span></p>
</div>
```